# Sequence of continously differentiable extended functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, uniform-convergence

Suppose a have a sequence of smooth real functions $f_n$ on $[0,1]$, which converges uniformly  to a smooth function $f$. Now consider the extended interval $E=[-0.5, 1.5]$. By Whitney's Theorem we know that $f$ admits a 'smooth' extension to whole of $E$. My question is: can $f_n$ be smoothly extended to $E$ so that $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E$? Any help on how to tackle this question is welcome.

Comment: And the definition of "smooth" is?

Comment: $k$ times continuously differentiable